# Would a civilization without war develop spaceflight?

Tags: technology, science-in-society

Could a peaceful extraterrestrial civilization (purely hypothetical) ever get to space?
I ask this because the vast majority of our technological milestones have come as the result of conflict:
Antibiotics => Saving soldiers in the trenches.
Rockets => German V2 used to bomb London.
Computers => To crack Enigma.
Nuclear power => The need to end the Second World War.
And so on..

---

If a civilization developed void of any war, (this includes Cold War) would they be able to get to the interstellar (FTL) age within a manageable period of time. Within 15,000 years. There is evidence that Humanity has been living in cities for up to 12,00 years, the oldest city (large town) has been dated back to 10,000 bc.

Comment: This will be very speculative, because we can only imagine a "peaceful civilization". How far this peacefulness go, and how is it achieved? Would members of this civilization be humans at all?

Comment: There are fictional worlds with and without war; and with and without space travel. I'm unsure what you're looking from us with this question. It looks more like you're wanting to discuss the possibilities of humanity rather than looking to build a fictional world.

Comment: With no constraints on what "a peaceful civilization" really means, then really an answer to this won't be much than "yes, probably" and perhaps noting that anything invented during war could be invented during peace given sufficient time/effort/motivation.

Comment: Biologically, how would they get to be the dominant civilisation without competitive urges manifesting in conflict? Surely, they'd just get outcompeted by something else which was warlike, can you clarify how they survived and what their drives are?

Comment: If you want quality answers we advise to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. Unsolved questions attract more attention, and at any moment users of this community are sleeping, working or doing anything else than being here in the 30 minutes you took to accept the first answer you got.

Comment: There's no way to know how long it would that to develop FTL because our sole example of a technological civilization ("hu-mans") hasn't actually got around to FTL yet and isn't convinced it's possible.  It might not be possile, it might take a million years.

Comment: Peter Watts' opinion on this matter might be of interest to you.

Comment: Your question structure is: Possibly viable conjecture => false supporting statement, =>false supporting statement, =>false supporting statement, =>false supporting statement.   Could I suggest you do some fact-checking on your supporting statements, then revisit your question's basic premise?

Answer (score 3):

Only social animals form civilizations. We tend to think of all intelligent aliens as "belonging to a civilization" because that's what we are ourselves, but it might be an unsafe assumption. Or, at least, it might be the low-effort assumption... it's much easier to speculate about aliens who aren't quite so alien.

Social animals, by their nature, will be probably be warlike. Social animals always form groups, and there are other competitive groups. These organisms will evolve on planets with scarce resources (that's the nature of our reality), and there will be conflict over those resources. Social animals reproduce, and so there will be population pressures. Living things seek to propagate their own genes to the exclusion of others' genes, therefor these social animals will have breakdowns in diplomacy that lead to war.

Given these basic principles, the idea that they will be "peaceful" is silly, or more properly belongs in straight fantasy rather than in science fiction. At least if they're social animals.

However, it's possible that there is some singular-consciousness, hivemind lifeform out there. What would be its motivations? How is it intelligent (intelligence may have evolved in humans so solve the social problems I presented above)? I could not say. But it's likely to have the following characteristics:

1. Its "peace" is the peace of never having encountered anything that would give it the concept of "enemy" before.
2. It seeks to and insists on consuming all resources that it has an appetite for.
3. It probably won't recognize that exterminating contenders for those resources as a moral issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when there would be a *strong and peaceful incentive* to do so.

**Mining the moon**

Suppose gold is very rare on the planet. But astronomers discovered large amounts of gold on the moon. For further development of electronics, more gold is needed, let's go and get it.

**Need satellites**

Earthlings take this offspin from the military for granted: communication satellites. Very handy for advanced civilizations, also peaceful ones.

**Scientific curiosity**

The moon was never researched. Could not be researched. Science wants to know what's up there. Because your peaceful people want to remain safe, and conditions in space are unknown: in preparation to go there, they could build a space station first, to do research on living conditions in space.

**To sell and deliver things**

Your peaceful civilization may not be alone. Suppose there are peaceful, non-hostile aliens on a nearby planet, but they don't have space travel either. The technology could be developed on both sides, a competition could result in both trying yo develop space travel quickly, to be first and have an advantage. A peaceful trade relation would develop, requiring transports.. or tourist travel..

**Heritage**

One day this peaceful civilization digs up a fully functional space ship, or space ship design. It is feasable to restore it, or rebuild it.

**Because we can**

As said in a previous answer, there will always exist an incentive to fly, or go into space. It is a strong wish, so space travel could become a goal in itself, without the need for support from a military-industrial complex. Chance is, when your planet has a good economy, it will become very rich.